# where to place web app server in AWS VPC ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, private-subnet

What is the best practice to place web app server in AWS VPC? In Private subnet with ELB or Public subnet?
As per my understanding the best practice is to place web app server in public subnet.

Comment: your question is too broad, where you are running the app and is it open to public or used internally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not place the web server in the public subnet. Launch them in a private subnet and front end them with ELB that runs in a public subnet. You do not want to deal with DDoS attacks on your web server, leave that to ELB which does an excellent job in addition to load balancing.

See:

- [How do I connect a public-facing load balancer to EC2 instances that have private IP addresses?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/public-load-balancer-private-ec2/)
- [Scenario 2: VPC with Public and Private Subnets (NAT)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html)